# How to create async JS ajax client for REST API if each API function invalidates auth key

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, asynchronous

What we have:

-REST API
-each call to it require auth key
-after each call we have new auth key (old key will be invalidated and new one will be created)

Question:

Is it a way to work with this API in async mode without key loss?

Any semaphores or other techniques ???

Greate thanks!

Comment: Trying to send new auth keys from headers..i done it as i say.